# C++ - Heap vs. Stack Attributes

Tags: c++, oop

Stack attributes:

```
class MyStackClass
{
public:
    MyStackClass (int a)
    {
        myType.create (a); // "create" is an alternative to Type constructor
    }    

private:
    Type myType;
};
```

Heap attributes:

```
class MyHeapClass
{
public:
    MyHeapClass (int a) {  myType = new Type (a);  }
    ~MyHeapClass () {  delete myType;  }

...

private:
    Type *myType;
};
```

I only use dynamic allocation when it's necessary, for example, dynamic arrays, variables that can don't exist, etc. But I've seen that some many programmers use heap allocation for attributes when it's not really necessary. What's the reason?, I mean, it's more expensive heap allocation than stack allocation. So, when should I use the "heap" way instead of the "stack" way??

Thanks.

Edit:
    Assuming that "MyHeapClass" have copy constructor, and `operator =` to meet the needs.

Comment: You're asking us to comment on the reasoning behind code we've never seen. You claim that it is "not really necessary". But without seeing the actual, specific code you're referring to, it's hard to say that you are right.

Comment: Do you want the default copy constructor to construct a new instance of the attribute?  Then use the stack attribute.  Otherwise the attribute  pointer will be copied and both will point to the same instance.

Comment: I think the OP is asking a general question about whether object fields should include object or point to the object off the heap, and the examples he has given are just to illustrate what he means by "stack attribute" vs "heap attribute", which aren't the accepted terminology.

Comment: Unless you can measure a performance issue, the only concern is safe and maintainable code.  But even if you use the heap, you should no longer use new or delete.

Comment: _"I've seen that some many programmers use heap allocation for attributes"_ Really? I haven't.

Comment: Depends on the language.  In some languages, allocation is always from the heap (without circumventing the language / compiler); so there is no choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fundamentally somewhat opinion based answer. However I will bring up a few matters that you should take into account here. In addition the C++ standard gives no mention to the stack or heap, only to variable scopes and lifetimes. Therefore this answer is implementation specific to systems whose C++ implementations actually use typical stacks and heaps.

### Size Limitations

The stack is usually substantially smaller than the heap. Often in the range of a few megabytes. The heap on the other hand is usually several gigabytes on modern systems.

If you put more on the stack than it allows your software might crash, or worse begin to act unpredictably. Therefore it is often better to allocate very large objects on the heap.

On the other hand there is substantial overhead to allocating heap objects as you mentioned, though there is the notable advantage that allocation can fail in a language defined way, which you can handle rather than a crash or worse in the case of a stack allocation failure.

### Passing Around and Returning

Second we need to bring up the cost of passing objects around. Specifically, heap objects are usually handled by pointer or reference, so passing these around is extremely cheap. The same can be done with stack objects except for the case they must survive for longer than the current scope. In that case they must either be copied (excepting move semantics or RVO), or you will be faced with using an expired stack frame, bad news and undefined behavior.

### Variable Length Objects

Finally we need to bring up objects of unpredictable size, like arrays, vectors etc. As far as I know there is not an easy way to allocate an object or runtime known size on the stack in the standard. The non standard alloca allows this but is dangerous in a variety of ways.

### Timing

In sections where timing is particularly critical, such as either a real tiem requirement or a tight performance critical loop the overheads of heap allocation are undesirable in multiple ways. Therefore one might lean toward stack allocation more.

However there are various work arounds to this, including preallocating the maximum amount of memory the timing cricial code might use in advance, using a memory allocator with a guaranteed O(1) time complexity (which is likely not useful normally due to slowness and inefficient memory use) or using an object pool or arena allocator to quickly recycle memory old heap objects of the same type used to avoid now allocations.

### In Conclusion

These points all sum up to a general rule that objects that are large, or of unpredictable and possibly large size should usually find themselves on the heap, while objects that are small, particularly if they are of a local scope and dont need to be passed around too much should go on the stack.

However this is not a hard and fast rule and there are a multitude of exceptions. A programmer in each case must give thought to the best location of an object.

Comment: Good write up.  A couple points: *"If you put more on the heap than"* - I think you mean stack there?  *"allocation can fail in a language defined way, which you can handle"* - though a modern OS tends to over-commit, often crashing at some unpredictable later time, whereas stack overflow tends to predictably bring down the app with a signal.

Comment: Tony, both heap and stack are finite, and attempts to over-allocate do fail. Over-allocation by modern OS reflects schemes like virtual memory, so they can allocate more memory than is physically available (and rely on swapping to disk when the allocated memory is needed). If you're referring to potential of a dynamic allocation to succeed, and subsequent shuffling between physical memory and swap space to fail, then yeah, sort of.  With modern OSs, that affects stack too, since heap and stack come from the same physical resources, and the distinction for the OS is academic apart from quotas.

Answer (score 1):

with C++11 and later, you should almost never use explicit (calling `new` and `delete`) heap allocation : it's more dangerous.

Using heap allocation for heap allocation is not a good way programming in C++.
You should (explicitly) use dynamic allocation only when you don't have any other choice.

Dynamic array and variable that may or may not exist require dynamic allocation but C++ standard provide classes for dealing with them easily (`vector`, `unique`/`shared`/`weak_ptr` and `optional` with C++17).
Of course, those classes use heap allocation, but they do it safely.

One of the uses of pointer are for non-copiable classes in standard containers, and for polymorphic types in container.
Anyway, you should always wrap resource management (pointer or files ...) in a class (see RAII idiom)

Comment: I disagree about using heap allocation.  Heap allocation is great when the amount of memory needed is only known at run-time.  However, dynamically allocated variables require more maintenance than other variables (such as using smart pointers).

Comment: Also, on some systems, large objects can only be allocated on the heap.  Large arrays are usually a bad idea to allocate on the stack.  Usually there is a size limit for global (static) allocations (on these systems, there is usually more dynamic memory available); so large data must be allocated in dynamic memory.

Comment: You should make clear that vectors and other container types still use heap allocation internally. They merely abstract it from the user to some degree. You seem to have not clearly distinguished heap allocation in the general sense and explicit allocation with the new operator or malloc etc.

Comment: *with C++11 and later, you should almost never use heap allocation* this is plain ridiculous.

Comment: I was talking about explicit heap allocation, of course you can't get ride of dynamic allocation, but with the "new" (C++11 and later), you almost never have to do it explicitly. If you need to do it explicitly, you should use RAII.

Answer (score 0):

In some languages variables are allocated from the heap, like C# and Java.

The C++ language offers more choices, such as local allocation (what you refer to as stack), heap and global/automatic location.

Java and C# have garbage collection and C++ doesn't.  The languages with garbage collection allow a 3rd party task to periodically go through the heap and cleanse (reorder) the memory so that more memory can be used.  This task does not exist in C++.

The C++ freedom allows one to declare variables and have them removed after they are not used (such as leaving scope).  Variables that need to exist beyond the scope they were declared in, are allocated on the heap (for example, creating variables used by many functions).  This eliminates the need to rely on a garbage collector.

On memory constrained systems, such as embedded devices, memory fragmentation is a big concerned.  Some systems, such as cell phones, can be power-cycled to defragment the memory.  Other systems, such as medical devices and aerospace devices, power cycling is not a preferred method for defragmenting the memory.  (Imagine rebooting an airplane's computer system while in flight at a high altitiude.).  So the idea is not to use heap memory and use other means.  The stack allocation is one of those means.

On some critical timing systems, meeting events is critical.  Having a garbage collector run at random intervals means that some of these critical events may be missed.  Fragmentation of heap memory is also detrimental in these systems.  Thus there needs to be some way of allocating variables without causing defragmentation.  The "stack" allocation method helps eliminate this issue.

Comment: *"local allocation (what you refer to as stack)"* - it's actually known in the Standard and C++ community as *automatic* allocation; the term is *not* used for global/namespace/"file" scope allocations.  Reference: [basic.stc.auto] 3.7.3 Automatic storage duration: Block-scope variables explicitly declared register or not explicitly declared `static` or `extern` have *automatic storage duration*. The storage for these entities lasts until the block in which they are created exits.

Comment: *"garbage collection allow a 3rd party task to periodically"* - isn't "implementation provided" more accurate than 3rd party?  More generally, you massively overstate the problems with memory fragmentation: in practice and for embedded devices as able as modern cell phones, "malloc" routines in e.g. Linux/Android or BSD/iOS cope well with heavy churn lasting months or years.